# How do you get from a byte[] or from a MemoryStream to a System.Windows.Controls.Image in WP7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I need to make a GET request that requires oauth, for and image to display in a page. Is there a way to do this without building a custom webrequest or httpwebrequest?

Comment: why did you ask the question twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPWebRequest GET with OAuth Header for an Image on Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699572/httpwebrequest-get-with-oauth-header-for-an-image-on-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an image make sure that you are reading the stream as binary data.

Something like:

```
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);

int lengthInBytes = Convert.ToInt32(httpResponse.ContentLength);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
byte[] imageInBytes = new byte[lengthInBytes]; 
using (br)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthInBytes; i++)
    {
        imageInBytes[i] = br.ReadByte();
    }
}

DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
{
    MemoryStream rawBytesStream = new MemoryStream(imageInBytes);
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

    img.SetSource(rawBytesStream);
    imageInUI.Source = img;
});
```